# Java - removeDuplicates

Tags: java

Given a `text` string, only remove *consecutive* duplicate  occurrences of the  same character, but the later occurrences of the    same character remain in the result as long as there was some other character between these occurrence.
Example: given argument `aaaabxaaddee` returns `abxade`.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```java
    char[] new_string = text.toCharArray();
    String result = "";

    for (int i = 1; i < text.length(); i++) {
        if (text.charAt(0) != text.charAt(i)) {
           text.charAt(0) = text.charAt(i);
           result += text.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return res;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you start with a `StringBuilder` whenever you want to mutate a sequence of characters in Java. Here you can loop from the left to the right, and start a second inner loop removing duplicate characters from the `StringBuilder`. Something like,

```
public static String removeDuplicates(String text) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text);
    for (int i = 0; i < sb.length() - 1;) {
        char ch = sb.charAt(i);
        int j = i + 1;
        while (j < sb.length() && sb.charAt(j) == ch) {
            sb.deleteCharAt(j);
        }
        i = j;
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Which I tested like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(removeDuplicates("aaaabxaaddee"));
}
```

And it outputs (as requested)

```
abxade
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple iterate over given string only once:

```java
public static String removeDuplicates(String str) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(str.length());
    char prv = '\0';

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);

        if (ch != prv)
            buf.append(ch);

        prv = ch;
    }

    return buf.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing with the first character only. Update your logic to compare the current char (at i) to the next (at i+1) and also start your loop from 0.

Answer (score 0):

You are only comparing the 0-th index of the char array which won't lead to the desired result. Also, you can't modify the string by `text.charAt(0) = text.charAt(i)`. It's invalid in Java.
Instead can use a `while` loop inside your for `loop` to check for consecutive occurrences. Keep checking if the current and next character in the string is *equal*. If they are equal then move ahead else break the while loop and continue with other iterations.

```java
for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
{
    result += text.charAt(i);
    while (i < text.length()-1 && text.charAt(i)==text.charAt(i+1))
        ++i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking in the right direction but instead of comparing each character with 0 index position character you can compare it with previous character since you have to ignore the consecutive ones .

```
char[] new_string = text.toCharArray();
       String result = ""+text.charAt(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < text.length(); i++) {
        if (text.charAt(i-1) != text.charAt(i)) {
              result += text.charAt(i);
        }
      }
       return result;   
        }
     }
```

Note:-

1. "text.charAt(0) = text.charAt(i)" This cannot be done in java as String is an immutable Class.
2. You are returning 'res' while you are storing the required string in 'result'.